# Morphia sorting by Date incorrect

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am using morphia framework, and I am unable to find a way to sort a dataset according to date. Morphia uses "order" method to sort the items according to a field in ascending or descending.

However in case of date, it is not sorting correctly.

Input dates: 19/12/2019 16:11, 17/12/2018 18:19, 19/12/2018 16:11, 17/12/2019 16:11

Sorted order: 19/12/2019 16:11, 19/12/2018 16:11, 17/12/2019 16:11, 17/12/2018 18:19

As seen here, it is not considering year into consideration while sorting. Please suggest me how can I achieve that using morphia.

Comment: It would be immensely helpful to see your model class and your query code.

Comment: Actually , my dates were in string format, so it was not sorting properly, I changed the date format to Date, and then sorting is happening correctly.